# Not able to save data instantly after clicking save button- kivy

Tags: python, kivy, text-files

I am trying to write in a text file after getting an input through TextInput in kivy. The problem is the data gets saved only after i close the app but i want the data to get saved as soon as I leave the specific screen and go to another screen. I am trying to input in add_staff and get it saved in the app through save() function.

```
import kivymd
import kivy
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
Builder.load_string('''
<MenuScreen>:
    nm:nm_input
    BoxLayout:
        TextInput:
            id:nm_input
        Button:
            text: 'Add New Staff'
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'add_staff'
        Button:
            text: 'View Staff Profile'
        Button:
            text: 'Salary report'

<Add_new_staff>:
    nam: str(name_input)
    job: job_input
    GridLayout:
        cols: 2
        Label:
            text: 'Name'
        TextInput:
            id: name_input
            multiline: False
        Label:
            text: 'Job'
        TextInput:
            id: job_input
        Label:
            text: 'Salary'
        TextInput:
        Label:
            text: 'Date of Joining'
        TextInput:
        Button:
            text: 'Back to menu'
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'menu'
        Button:
            text: 'Save'
            on_press: root.save(name_input.text, job_input.text);root.manager.current = 'menu'
''')


class MenuScreen(Screen):
    pass

class Add_new_staff(Screen):
    def save(self, name, job):
        fob = open('testi.txt','a')
        fob.write(name + "\n")
        fob.write(job)
        fob.close()


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(MenuScreen(name='menu'))
        sm.add_widget(Add_new_staff(name='add_staff'))
        return sm
    def lo(self,nm):
        f=open('log.txt','a')
        f.write(nm)
        f.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Comment: +1 for a great minimal working example. Although I can't reproduce the effect: The `testi.txt` is created and written to immediately when I hit the "Save" button.

Comment: I tried your example also and it is saved for me immediately... without closing the app I switched to my files viewer app and the testi.txt file was there, add a second name and also, that saved too....

Comment: Could it, maybe, be saving in a unintentional location? This happens me sometimes, I don't know why cause I never tried to figure it out bit sometimes, it's in a folder I wasn't expecting it to be in